# Rock Paper Scissor Javascript using arrays? beginner

Tags: javascript

I am new member here and new to JavaScript. Didn't start coding until 4 weeks ago. Learned html then css, now JavaScript.

I'm trying to make an `rps game`, but using arrays and with less **math** so to speak. Apologies if the code is messy.

I can't get it to show anything in the console log. Does this code make any sense?

```
var rPs = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"] 
var random = rPs[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];

function random(you, computer){
    if (you===computer){
        console.log ("It's a tie!");

    } else if (you==="Rock"&&computer==="Scissors"||you==="Paper"&&computer==="Rock"||you==="Scissors"&&computer==="Paper") {
        console.log ("You've won!");

    } else {

        console.log ("You've lost!");

    }

};
```

Comment: you have a function and a string values with the same name `random` where are you trying to call the functon?

Comment: Are you calling the function random(you, computer) properly elsewhere in your script ?

Comment: I will advice you to change the name of your function like so random_fn(you,computer). Never use a variable name that is the same as one of your function name.

Answer (score 2):

Cool, you are almost there! There are two things you're missing.

- We need 2 players! Create a second random variable, or a second player if you like.
- Then you need to invoke your `random()` function, or nothing will happen.

Try this:

```
var rPs = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
// We need two random variables, one for 'you'
var you = rPs[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
// and one for the 'computer'
var computer = rPs[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];

// Now invoke function
random(you, computer);

function random(you, computer){
    if (you===computer){
         console.log ("It's a tie!");
    } else if (you==="Rock" && computer === "Scissors" || you === "Paper" && computer==="Rock"||you==="Scissors"&&computer==="Paper") {
         console.log ("You've won!");
    } else {
         console.log ("You've lost!");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks so much everyone for the input. i really appreciate the help. looking forward to becoming a part of the community :) i will be here much more with questions... and hopefully as i get better, i get to contribute answers as well :)

Comment: @giantqtipz Welcome to the community! Please mark the answer as accepted if you found it helpful :)